# why bootstrap is not accessible to _Layout.cshtml child

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using mvc-5 and using bootstrap and all my links are in  _Layout.cshtml now i have a drop down tabs like this http://prntscr.com/75qqpp (using bootstrap) now in my
_Layout.cshtml i have `renderbody()` which renders all my UI .

What i want to ?
On clicking the tab "Real Time" i get a dropdown list which on futher click to "Tabular" must open replace the current view just below the tabs to a new view .

How i try to do this ?

(1) In home controller i do this :

```
 public ActionResult tabular()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

(2) Then i create view and in that view i add Layout path like this :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "tabular";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>tabular</h2>
```

As a result i have all the tabs but they are not alligned properly it now shows the view like this: http://prntscr.com/75qxaz 
I feel like i dont have access to bootstrap here or i am doing anything wrong ?

Could some one please give guidance such that i can have tabular.cshtml view just below the tab in the first link (this tab will be common to all the views obtained)

My full code is:

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <!--starts here-->

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.6.2/modernizr.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!--click on main tab disappers-->


    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/jquery.easy-pie-chart.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/bootstrap/css/DT_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/jquery.jgrowl.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/cssFiles.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Bootstrap -->

    <link href="bootstrap/css/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/DT_bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="/static/vendors/jGrowl/jquery.jgrowl.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="bootstrap/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="bootstrap/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="bootstrap/css/datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/uniform.default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/chosen.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-wysihtml5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/dataTables.tableTools.css" />

    <!--   <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> <!--click on main tab disappers-->
    <!--  <script src="bootstrap/js/common.js"></script>   hover disappears-->

    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.easy-pie-chart.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.jgrowl.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery-DT-pagination.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/icon-selector.js"></script>


    <script src="bootstrap/js/dashboard.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js"></script>



    <script src="bootstrap/js/jquery.bootstrap.wizard.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/raphael-min.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/morris.min.js"></script>
    <!--ends here-->
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-fixed-top">
                        <div class="navbar-inner">
                            <div class="container-fluid">
                                <div class="navbar-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                    </button>
                                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/dashboard/">Vision Vertex</a>
                                </div>

                                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                Real Time
                                                <i class="caret"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="~/Views/Shared/_Layout/">Dashboard</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <!--onclick="tabularFunction()" -->
                                                    @*<a tabindex="-1" href="~/Views/Home/BackgroundViews/tabular.cshtml">Tabular</a>*@
                                                    @Html.ActionLink("Tabular", "tabular", "Home")
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/map/">Live Map</a>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>

                                        <li class="dropdown">
                                            <a href="#" role="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                                Utilites<i class="caret"></i>
                                            </a>
                                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/contact-list/">List Contacts</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/contact-registration/">Add Contact</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/notification-list/">List Notification</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/notification-registration/">Add Notification</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/report-list/">List Periodic Report</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/report-registration/">Add Periodic Report</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/list-period-alert/">List Periodic Alert</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="/dashboard/add-period-alert/">Add Periodic Alert</a>
                                                </li>
                                                <!--li class="divider"></li>
                                                <li>
                                                    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">FAQ</a>
                                                </li-->
                                            </ul>
                                        </li>                                              
                                    </ul>             
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

HomeController :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace testLayt.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult tabular()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

tabular.cshtml :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "tabular";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>tabular</h2>
```

Comment: You can do this by using PartialView

Comment: @AmarKamthe Ok, Thanks but . Could you please get me idea that whats wrong in the current method ?

Comment: @AmarKamthe i tried even that with same code except that instead of tabular.cshtml  i have tabularSharedPartial.cshtml  which do exactly the same.

Comment: Did you try not using the explicit "Layout" setting in tabular.cshtml?  It should, by default, use it if you have a _ViewStart.cshtml that already specifies it.

Comment: @JasonWilczak please explain in detail . i am newbee and i understand nothing with this brief explanation

Comment: @ajpr IF you have a _ViewStart.cshtml in your Views folder structure, then it should, if you open it, have a line for your layout.  By default, your views will use the ViewStart and whatever layout is specified there, so you don't need to specify it again.  In your partials, when you don't want to use a layout (since the view that the partial is in should use the layout), you would have to set Layout = null;